# solicitud post no llega al controller api desde xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

vengo a ustedes porque ya tengo dos dias en este problema, espero y me puedan dar una mano. gracias desde antes.

cuando envio datos por post(el unico metodo que he probado) desde mi aplicacion de xamarin hacia mi api en asp net core5 estos datos nunca llegan al controller.
cuando realizo la peticion a mi api desde postman esta funciona sin problemas.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el error que me muestra la consulta desde xamarin [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui muestro la mi post desde xamarin [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi controller

```
[Route("CreateAccount")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAccount([FromBody] CreateAccount createAccount)
    {
        try
        {
            bool validateClientExistence = await _IcreateAccountService.ValidateClientExistence(createAccount);

            if (validateClientExistence)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "El "+ createAccount.PhoneNumber + " ya esta registrado :(" });

            }
            await _IcreateAccountService.CreateAccountNew(createAccount);

            return Ok(new { message = "Gracias por registrarte :)" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return BadRequest(new { message = "Ha ocurrido un error :( " + ex});
        }
    }
```

este es mi manifest .xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les agradeceria toda ayuda. gracias

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: parece chiste xd. el unico comentario y ni tratas de ayudar, pero al menos no mencionaste la palabra mas usada *pregunta duplicada*.

Comment: Si no te parece ayuda las recomendaciones de cómo preguntar, pues, creo que deberías expandir un poquito más el concepto de ayuda, hay varias preguntas que han obtenido una mejor aceptación justamente por seguir esas recomendaciones (llevo años por aquí) y si no te parece adecuado expandir el concepto que tienes de ayuda, normal, no pasa nada~ Hakuna Matata. Por otro lado, no he visto un escenario idéntico en el sitio como para considerar tu pregunta como duplicada, finalmente, me alegra que hayas podido resolver tu pregunta :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funcionando...
al parecer xamarin o mejor dicho, el emulador android no le gusta trabajar con apis en local.publique mi api en ngrok y ahora funciona sin problemas